# ChangeTracker.Entries() always null

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I got a problem with my homework project. Using Entity Framework 6.2.0 . I have some entity which are inherited from IEntity interface

```
public interface IEntity
{
    int Id { get; set; }
    DateTime CreateDate { get; set; }
    DateTime UpdateDate { get; set; }
}
```

And I want CreateDate and UpdateDate auto assign when save changes, so I overrided SaveChanges() method in my Context

```
public override int SaveChanges()
{
    ChangeTracker.DetectChanges();
    var entityEntries = ChangeTracker.Entries(); //null
    //var entityEntries = ChangeTracker.Entries<IEntity>(); this is null, too
    //var entityEntries = ChangeTracker.Entries().Where(entity => entity is IEntity); I tried to uses this, entityEntries still null

    foreach (var entity in entityEntries)
    {
        if (entity is IEntity autoEntry)
        {
            if (entity.State == EntityState.Added)
            {
                autoEntry.CreateDate = DateTime.Now;
                autoEntry.UpdateDate = DateTime.Now;
            }
            else
            {
                autoEntry.UpdateDate = DateTime.Now;
            }
        }
    }
    return base.SaveChanges();
}
```

But `entityEntries` always null so I can't set value to `CreateDate` and `UpdateDate` Properties. My foreach loop never run.

My context class below

```
public class KarnelContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Account> Accounts { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Role> Roles { get; set; }

    public KarnelContext() : base("name=learningDB")
    {
    }
    public override int SaveChanges()
    {
        ChangeTracker.DetectChanges();
        var entityEntries = ChangeTracker.Entries<IEntity>();
        //var entityEntries = ChangeTracker.Entries().Where(entity => entity is IEntity);

        foreach (var entity in entityEntries)
        {
            if (entity is IEntity autoEntry)
            {
                if (entity.State == EntityState.Added)
                {
                    autoEntry.CreateDate = DateTime.Now;
                    autoEntry.UpdateDate = DateTime.Now;
                }
                else
                {
                    autoEntry.UpdateDate = DateTime.Now;
                }
            }
        }
        return base.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

What's wrong with my code?

Thanks for helping

Comment: please show your Context class, this information is not enough to know what is the problem

Comment: I added my context Class @EhsanSajjad

Comment: your entties are implementing IEntity right and how you are calling the context ?

Comment: Yes, my entities are implementing `IEntity` and I call the context by `var context = new KarnelContext()` then `context.Accounts.Add(account);`

Comment: what happens if you omit the DetectChanges() call? In your scenario it doesn't matter (it will be called afterwards anyways, and added state is not set by ChangeTracker).

Comment: I got somewhere on stackoverflow that call `DetectChanges()` before call  `ChangeTracker.Entries()`, but seem there are nothing change when I call `DetectChanges()`. My `entityEntries` still null

Comment: There are noone can help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a problem

```
public override int SaveChanges()
{
    ChangeTracker.DetectChanges();
    var entityEntries = ChangeTracker.Entries(); //null
    //var entityEntries = ChangeTracker.Entries<IEntity>(); this is null, too
    //var entityEntries = ChangeTracker.Entries().Where(entity => entity is IEntity); I tried to uses this, entityEntries still null

    foreach (var entity in entityEntries)
    {
        if (entity is IEntity autoEntry)// <- Problem here, since enity never be IEntity type. 
        //Should change to entity.Entity is IEntity autoEntry
        {
            if (entity.State == EntityState.Added)
            {
                autoEntry.CreateDate = DateTime.Now;
                autoEntry.UpdateDate = DateTime.Now;
            }
            else
            {
                autoEntry.UpdateDate = DateTime.Now;
            }
        }
    }
    return base.SaveChanges();
}
```

I still don't understand why `entityEntries = ChangeTracker.Entries<IEntity>();` always null whenever I add watch it. But my problem about auto datetime is solved.